# Trying to go to a diffrent intent from a fragment

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to go to a diffrent intwent when a button is press in my fragment.
When the button is press it calls the following method:

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActGetKey.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Whare the first line gives a  Cannot resolve constructer error from the following line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActGetKey.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The code:
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    View temp;

    temp =  view.findViewById(R.id.MENhOME);
    temp.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v){
    // error
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActGetKey.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActGetKey.class);
```

with below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActGetKey.class);
```

Hope this helps you.